# Date range comparison using varchar columns in Teradata

Tags: sql, coldfusion, teradata

I've been tasked to take a calendar date range value from a form front-end and use it to, among other things, feed a query in a Teradata table that does not have a datetime column.  Instead the date is aggregated from two varchar columns:  one for year (CY = current year, LY = last year, LY-1, etc), and one for the date with format MonDD (like Jan13, Dec08, etc).

I'm using Coldfusion for the form and result page, so I have the ability to dynamically create the query, but I can't think of a good way to do it for all possible cases.  Any ideas?  Even year differences aside, I can't think of anything outside of a direct comparison on each day in the range with a potential ton of separate OR statements in the query.  I'm light on SQL knowledge - maybe there's a better way to script it in the SQL itself using some sort of conversion on the two varchar columns to form an actual date range where date comparisons could then be made?

Comment: try to revise your question :)

Comment: What is the structure (column names and data types) of the Teradata table you want to query?

Comment: Can you provide samples of the data and results you are looking for?

Comment: What type of db is it?  sql server?  oracle?  something else?  or is Teradata a type of db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some SQL that will take the `VARCHAR` date value and perform some basic manipulations on it to get you started:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST('Jan18'||TRIM(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURRENT_DATE)) AS CHAR(9)) AS DATE FORMAT 'MMMDDYYYY') AS BaseDate_
     , CASE WHEN Col1 = 'CY'
            THEN BaseDate_
            WHEN Col1 = 'LY'
            THEN ADD_MONTHS(BaseDate_, -12)
            WHEN Col1 = 'LY-1'
            THEN ADD_MONTHS(BaseDate_, -24)
            ELSE BaseDate_
       END AS DateModified_
  FROM {MyDB}.{MyTable};
```

The `EXTRACT()` function allows you to take apart a `DATE`, `TIME`, or `TIMESTAMP` value.
You have you use `TRIM()` around the `EXTRACT` to get rid of the whitespace that is added converting the `DATEPART` to a `CHAR` data type. Teradata is funny with dates and often requires a double `CAST()` to get things sorted out.

The `CASE` statement simply takes the encoded values you suggested will be used and uses the `ADD_MONTHS()` function to manipulate the date. Dates are `INTEGER` in Teradata so you can also add `INTEGER` values to them to move the date by a whole day. Unlike Oracle, you can't add fractional values to manipulate the `TIME` portion of a `TIMESTAMP`. `DATE` != `TIMESTAMP` in Teradata.

Comment: Thanks Rob.  This is what I was looking for!  Now I just have to root out bad date data in the MMMDD column somewhere.

Comment: Ah, the "bad data" is just me having to be a bit more careful with leap years / Feb29 in this manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Rob gave you an sql approach.  Alternatively you can use ColdFusion to generate values for the columns you have.  Something like this might work.

```
sampleDate = CreateDate(2010,4,12);  // this simulates user input

if (year(sampleDate) is year(now())
    col1Value = 'CY';
else if (year(now()) - year(sampleDate) is 1)
    col1Value = 'LY'
else
    col1Value = 'LY-' & DateDiff("yyyy", sampleDate, now());

col2Value = DateFormat(sampleDate, 'mmmdd');
```

Then you send col1Value and col2Value to your query as parameters.